# How do I make templateURL scroll into certain part of a page?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, route-provider

Can you guys help me with my routeProvider?

```
$routeProvider.when('/farm', {
        templateUrl: '/index.htm#farm'
    });
```

`#farm` doesn't work. I wanted it so that when somebody clicks the **Farm** link from outlook, it would go to the index page and scroll down to where there is an id of `farm`. My div already has an ID of farm too so no problem with that I guess.

I've read a lot of sources and solutions but all of them say that anchor tags doesn't work on templateURL. I was wondering if you guys got a work around for this.

By the way, sample link is: `www.test.com/index#farm`
Clicking on that link in outlook email won't scroll down to where `#farm` is.
Instead, it goes to the index page and turns the URL into only `/index` without the `#farm`

Here is another part of my code in case maybe these guys are messing with it:

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');

    $routeProvider.when('/index', {
        templateUrl: '/index.htm'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/farm', {
        templateUrl: '/index.htm#farm'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/error', {
        templateUrl: '/error.htm'
    });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/index' });
```

I think that the `.otherwise` is making it go to index.htm. 
Is there any other way to just add another routeProvider and templateURL that may scroll down to where farm is in the index page?

When I tried `templateURL: '/index.html#farm'` it only went to `/index%23farm` which doesn't scroll down.

So basically the link is external (from email) and if they click it I want them to scroll down to where `#farm` is.

Comment: Hello, I've also tried using 
```
```app.controller('farmController', function ($scope, $location, $anchorScroll, $routeParams) {
});


app.run(function ($rootScope, $location, $anchorScroll, $routeParams) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (newRoute, oldRoute) {
        var old = $location.hash()
        $location.hash($routeParams.scrollTo);
        $anchorScroll();
    });
})```
```
and changing the link in the email to www.test.com/#/index?scrollTo=farm
but it's still not working.

Answer (score 1):

Use $anchorScroll();

Inject $anchorScroll into your controller and use it as such.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll

```
 // the element you wish to scroll to.
  $location.hash('farm’);

  // call $anchorScroll()
  $anchorScroll();
```

Comment: Hi @tbone894 I'd like to ask something. Since this is from an external site (Outlook email) therefore I cannot use <a ng-click="scrollTo('farm')">Farm</a> but can only use Outlook's link feature where if they click this URL: www.website.com/farm then supposedly they'd be at this site: www.website.com/index#farm. How do I do that with $anchorscroll? I've tried lots of ways but it ain't working. I can give my code if needed too. I'm really sorry, I'm new to angular JS.

Comment: Those URLs are not the same. The first takes you to the farm route while the other takes you to the index.html and to #farm element. In the email you should be sending the same link as where you want them to go. So i am assuming you want them to go to your 2nd url listed with #farm. So in your controller connected to your index route, you would place the code I mentioned.

Comment: Ahh right, I was thinking that routeprovider could change the templateURL if they visit /farm so that it would look cleaner in the email without the hashtag. Anyway, this is what I did tbone, can you tell me what is wrong here? 

[link](https://codepen.io/noses/pen/JjYMNBb)

I seriously do not know what I am doing rn. Sorry, I'm new to this.

Comment: Ok that’s a lot to go through. Lots of stuff to clean up. It might be easier to show you some examples. Let me think how to do this.

Comment: https://codepen.io/tbone849/pen/PoPEQRR?editors=1010

I changed a lot of what you did. Look at all the comments. Tried to explain everything. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: So I've read your comments and understood a lot. It still didn't work as I used your sample so I updated the codepen to the code. Some fails that I've tested are in the CSS area written as a comment and some thoughts of what might have made it not scroll down.

https://codepen.io/noses/pen/JjYMNBb

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213213/discussion-between-nolan-kr-and-tbone849).